# Fill bootstrap dropdown with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have song objects from the server from which I get via ng-repeat via AngularJS, and I can fill an ugly dropdown this way:

```
<select name="songs" ng-model="songs">
         <option ng:repeat="x in songs" value="{{x.artist}}">{{x.artist}} - {{x.title}}</option>
     </select>
```

But when I have a bootstrap dropdown that looks graphically good, it doesn't work

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="chooseSongDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            Choose song
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="chooseSongDropdown">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li ng-repeat"x in songs">{{x.title}}</li>
        </ul>


        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="choosePlaylistDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            Choose playlist
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="choosePlaylistDropdown">
    </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps make a small jsfiddle etc to better see the issues.

Comment: you are missing the `=` in here: `ng-repeat"x in songs"`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [angular directives for bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).  They have multiple examples for you to choose from.  The markup would look something like this.

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle >
        Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li ng-repeat="song in songs"><a href="#">{{song.title}}</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```